# vArray values not clearing out from previous loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have some vArrays which are not clearing out. The purspose of the macro is to work on a raw data tab which has 30+ tabs, each tab holding information for a specific office, 001-New York, etc. The macro is supposed to select x number of tabs (based on a reference file), copy them and save them into a new workbook. The problem is that instead of copying and saving from the raw data file it save the reference file instead. A For...Next loop is used to determine which tabs/offices to select & copy from the raw data file. The varrays are inside the loop and contain the names of the offices. When the code encounters the vArray the varray values are not clearing out when the loop circles back around.

Example:

'For 1' reference a cell with value of "8" so it populates 8 different vArray values (offices in this case). 'For 2' has a reference number of 5 and is supposed to populate 5 vArray values. It does this correctly as I can see the 5 new values in the locals window under vArray (1) thru vArray (5), however, vArray 6 thru 8 are showing values of the previous loop instead of 'Empty'. The vArray values are not clearing out when the macro loops.

sMasterListWBName is the reference file which tells the macro which tabs to copy from the raw data file and where to move the newly created workbook. The sub is also copying, saving, and distributing the reference file instead of the raw data file for some iterations of the loop (secondary issue--I will try to refrain from splitting the thread topic).

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to answer this question.

```
Option Explicit
Dim iYear As Integer, iMonth As Integer, iVer As Integer, icount As Integer, iCount2 As Integer
Dim iLetter As String, iReport As String
Dim sMonth As String, sDate As String, sVer As String, sAnswer As String
Dim sFolderName As String, sManagerInitials  As String
Dim iManagerNumber As Integer, iManagerStart As Integer, iTabNumber As Integer, iTabStart As Integer
Dim sMasterListWBName As String, sConsolidatedWBName As String, sExists As String
Dim oSheet As Object, oDistList As Object
Dim vArray(300) As Variant
Dim wbDistList As Workbook
Dim wsAgentListSheet As Worksheet, wsMain As Worksheet
Dim rCell As Range, rCell2 As Range, rCellTotal As Range
Public sFINorAgent As String


Sub Agent_Distribute()
On Error Resume Next

iYear = frm_fin_rep_main_distribute.txt_year
iMonth = frm_fin_rep_main_distribute.txt_month
iVer = frm_fin_rep_main_distribute.txt_version

sMonth = Right("0" & iMonth, 2)
sDate = iYear & "." & sMonth

sVer = "V" & iVer
sAnswer = MsgBox("Is the following information correct?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Report - " & frm_fin_rep_main.sLetter & vbNewLine & _
                    "Year - " & iYear & vbNewLine & _
                    "Month - " & sMonth & vbNewLine & _
                    "Name - " & frm_fin_rep_main.sReport & vbNewLine & _
                    "Version - " & sVer, vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Please verify...")
If sAnswer <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Unload frm_fin_rep_main_distribute
frm_agent.Hide
Form_Progress

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

sConsolidatedWBName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sMasterListWBName = "Dist Master List Final.xls"
If Not IsFileOpen(sMasterListWBName) Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
    "W:\Addins\01 GL - Distribution\" & sMasterListWBName, Password:="password"
    Workbooks(sConsolidatedWBName).Activate
End If

Set oDistList = Workbooks(sMasterListWBName).Worksheets("Agent")

With oDistList

    iManagerNumber = .Range("ManNumber2") 'range value = 66

    For iManagerStart = 2 To iManagerNumber '2 to 66
        If .Range("A" & iManagerStart) = "x" Then

            iTabNumber = .Range("E" & iManagerStart) 'E2 to E66
            sFolderName = .Range("F" & iManagerStart) 'F2 to F66
            sManagerInitials = .Range("G" & iManagerStart) 'G2 to G66

                For iTabStart = 1 To iTabNumber
                    vArray(iTabStart) = .Range("G" & iManagerStart).Offset(0, iTabStart)
                Next iTabStart

                If iTabNumber = 1 Then
                    Sheets(vArray(1)).Select
                Else
                    Sheets(vArray(1)).Select
                    For iTabStart = 2 To iTabNumber
                        Sheets(vArray(iTabStart)).Select False
                    Next iTabStart
                End If

                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy

                ' *** the following code is optional, remove preceding apostrophes from the following four lines to enable password protection ***
                'For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                    'oSheet.Protect "password"
                    'oSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
                'Next

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
                "W:\Financials\" & iYear & "\" & sDate & "\Report to Distribute Electronically\Department Reports\" _
                & sFolderName & "\Current Year Financials" & "\" & "Y" & ") " & iYear & "-" & sMonth & " Agent Report Card " & sVer & " - " & sManagerInitials & ".xls"
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If

        iPercent = iManagerStart / iManagerNumber * 95
        Task_Progress (iPercent)
    Next iManagerStart
End With

Workbooks(sMasterListWBName).Close False

Task_Progress (100)
Unload frm_progress

Set oDistList = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Message_Done

frm_agent.Show (vbModeless)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `vArray` declared? I only see assignments in the posted code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to included the declarations. I added them just now. Thanks.

Comment: That's your problem - vArray is a module level variable. Just clear it with `Erase vArray` at the start of the `Sub`.

Comment: It worked! I knew it was the vArray causing it just didn't know why. Thank you!

Comment: `sMonth = Right("0" & iMonth, 2)` - no need for that Select Case

Comment: It's happening again. The 'Erase vArray' fix appeared to work but now it's not working for all the files. Erase vArray at the start of the sub doesn't appear to clear out the vArray in between loops. I added "Erase vArray" inside the loop (before "Next iManagerStart") and it was an improvement but it still didn't work for the last 8 instances/files of the loop. Where inside the sub should the "Erase vArray" go in order for this thing to work for all iterations of the loop?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`? You might as well write `On Error Hide Bug`. It is almost always a bad idea to use it the way that you are using it (with no attempt to manually check `Err.Number`). Also -- your code has nothing to do with the `varray` tag (which is fairly specific to PL/SQL), so I will remove that tag but add `excel-vba` instead.

Comment: I just ran macro in debug mode(F8), stepping thru the entire sub from start to finish, observing all important expressions in Watch window. F8 got stuck(did not respond) right after "ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy" line & anytime a new file was opened/created. Each time I had to click VB editor window to resume. The entire macro ran successfully when I got done. But when I ran it the usual way, using the form, only the first 17 files got saved w/the raw data, the other 23 got saved with the ref. file data. I suspect the window activation is to blame.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran the macro again a few times in run mode (using the form) and each time the success rate is random (20%, 75%, 30%, etc.) but never 100%, meaning that out of 40 files the macro saves, only some of them get saved with the correct raw data. The others get saved with the reference file data which is useless. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I just added "Workbooks(sWbName).activate" at the end of the loop to make sure the focus is back on the raw data file. Now all files are saving in the correct format and location. Case closed unless someone has anything else to add. Maybe someone knows the reason the macro was losing sight of its active sheet (saving reference file instead of raw data file). Thank you.